# MIRROR | ЯOЯЯIM

Tags: code-golf

### Challenge

Given the equation of a line and the coordinates of the vertices of a shape, output the coordinates of the shape when reflected across the given line.

### Further Information

The line's equation will be given with a `y` and an `x` separated by an equals sign (there may not always be a `y` and an `x`). Some examples:

```
y=x
y=5.0
y=2.4x
x=6.6
y=2.0x+5.0
x=2.0y
```

The equation will always be supplied as a string.

The line will *always* be linear.

The equation will only contain `+`s or `-`s and any multiplication will be before an `x` or a `y`. The `*` is not used however, and the number will be placed directly before the variable.

A `0.0` is never used in the equation because there is no need for it to be shown.

The coordinates will be an array of length `n>2` of arrays of length `2`. Outputted coordinated must also be in a similar array.

No numbers supplied will be greater than `(2^32)-1` or less than `-((2^32)-1)`. All supplied numbers will be floats, and the output is expected to be the same.

The program may either be a full program or a function (a function may be easier for passing the coordinates).

### Example

```
Input: y=5.0 [(0.0,0.0),(0.0,4.0),(5.0,0.0),(5.0,4.0)]
Output: [(0.0,10.0),(0.0,6.0),(5.0,10.0),(5.0,6.0)]

Input: x=3.5y [(1.14,2.04),(4.16,5.86),(6.02,0.86),(4.2,2.44)]
Output: [(2.05,-1.13),(6.63,-2.78),(5.57,2.45),(4.86,0.15)]
```

### Winning

The shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: Will the text for the line always have a variable by itself on the left? Also, will the only operations occurring in the line's formula be addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division? Do we need to support parentheses? Exponents?

Comment: As a side note, it'd be really helpful if you would write `y=2.4x` as `y=2.4*x` in the input, for example...

Comment: Good thing that the line is always linear. I hate those non-linear lines. :) Is it guaranteed that each variable only shows up in the equation once? For example, could it be: `y=5x+3x+7`?

Comment: Shouldn't the line in the example be `y=4.5` instead?

Comment: @DLosc No matter which coordinate is which, the example looks more like a translation than a reflection to me. It adds the given `x` value to the coordinates, instead of mirroring at the line given by the value.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yep, only once :)

Comment: @mbomb007 No exponents because the line is linear

Comment: Thanks for fixing the examples. Can you also answer @mbomb007's earlier questions? I think we need a much more precise definition of the expression syntax. Or do the examples cover all possible forms of the expression? Meaning that the only operators are the `+` and the multiplication with constants, where the `*` is not written? Are constants always floating point with digits before and after the decimal point?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Do you need any more clarification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## მƧƎ ɈqiɿɔƧɒvɒႱ, <s>54</s> <s>47</s> <s>88</s> <s>65</s> <s>60</s> 67 bytes

<sub>**JavaScript ES6**</sub>

I've updated to the new question specifications.

```
(a,b)=>b.map(l=>([y,x]=l,l[g=a[0]>'x']+=l[g]-eval(a.slice(2))*2,l))
```

I've defined variables x and y to their corrosponding value so we can eval the expression to get the value. Using `[x,y]=l`, we can easilt set x to `l[0]` and y to `l[1]`

```
(a,b)=>b.map(l=>([x,y]=l,l[a[0]<'y'|0]+=eval(a.slice(2)),l))
```

Broken up:

```
(a,b)=>  // Function with args: a and b
  b.map(l=> . Loops through b
    (
      l[ // Gets x or y depending on condition
         a[0]<'y'|0 // x returns 0, y returns 1
      ]
      += // plus...
      eval( // evaluate the following expression
        a.slice(2).replace( // Replace the input expression
          /x|y/g, // Match 'x' and 'y'
          l=>
             `*l[${l<'y'|0}]`) // Multiple previous value by corresponding value
        )
    ,l)) // Returns new coordinates
```

---

The old version which didn't expect variables on the right-hand side, **(47 bytes)**

```
(a,b)=>b.map(l=>(l[a[0]<'y'|0]+=+a.slice(2),l))
```

Running it (second example):

```
[[2.05, -1.13], [6.63, -2.78], [5.57, 2.45], [4.86, 0.15]]
```

Comment: Wow the idea to `eval` the input is genius.